# Byte array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, byte

How can I create a byte array in Objective-C?

I have some data like this:`0x12, 0x23, 0x34, 0x45, 0x56, 0x67, 0x78, 0x89, 0x12, 0x23, 0x34, 0x45, 0x56, 0x67, 0x78, 0x89`, that I want to prepare as a byte array.

Answer (score 36):

You can simply use plain C syntax, which is available in Objective-C:

```
const char myByteArray[] = {
    0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,
    0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89,
    0x12,0x23,0x34,0x45,
    0x56,0x67,0x78,0x89 };
```

Comment: what's the difference if an unsigned char was used?

Comment: I love the C byte array but what happens if you want multiple byte arrays inside `NSArray`?  `Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type 'const char *' to 'id _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC`.  I like the answerr below from @Georg.  `NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];` ?

Comment: In case I have some data like this (a NSString object) @"0x12, 0x23, 0x34, 0x45, 0x56, 0x67, 0x78, 0x89, 0x12, 0x23, 0x34, 0x45, 0x56, 0x67, 0x78, 0x89", how would I programmatically create an unsigned char array?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Either use the plain C solution given by mouviciel or read the class description of [`NSData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata?language=objc) and [`NSMutableData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledata?language=objc).

Comment: These links should be updated - NSData: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata - NSMutableData: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledata