# Converting bytearray to Objective-C data structure

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Byte array in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876598/byte-array-in-objective-c)

Am converting some Java code to Objective-C and have run into an issue that I can't get my head around:

```
public static final byte[] DATA_GENERIC = new byte[] { (byte)0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03,
            0x10, 0x10 };
```

Does anyone know to convert the above into Objective-C

Comment: This thread contains the information you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876598/byte-array-in-objective-c

Comment: @Perception thanks for quick reply. I seen that post but couldn't take any further. I can create the char array but then don't know how to interact it using Objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of getting your data into a `NSData` object.

```
const unsigned char bytes[] = { 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x10, 0x10 };
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:7];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Output:

**`<a0000000 031010>`**

One major difference from java is you will need to keep track of the number of bytes yourself when working with a raw char array. Once you create the `NSData` you can access the length.

Comment: thanks very much worked a treat so is a Java type "Byte" equivalent to NSData

Comment: NSData is closer to a Byte[]. Byte in Java is a class where in C/Objective-C it would be represented as an unsigned char. They are still quite different.